# EXCEL: Take the average of a column in row (n-5,n-1) if row n fulfills a condition

Tags: excel

There are 50 rows. The first column (A), each row has has a ID number. They are not sorted in any way and should not be either and there are no duplicated ID numbers. When the ID is 0 then consider 4 rows before that row, take the mean value of those values in clumn C between those 4 rows. If it helps It is always the last row that has value ID = 0.

What I have done so far is that I can find the ROW number of the `ID = 0` using the following formula:

```
ROW(INDEX(A3:A53,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A3:A53=0,),0)))
```

Now I don't know how to navigate 4 rows upwards and take the corrosponding values in Column C.

Comment: You probably want to research `OFFSET()`, but note that it can slow down calculation a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an extra column (say column Z), then paste this code into that column starting on row 4 (NB it won't work properly for the first 3 rows because there are not 4 above to check).

```
=IF($A4 =0, AVERAGE($C1:$C4), "Not Relevant")
```

so put that code in Z4, then press ctrl+E to flash fill it downwards.

Hopefully, on each line where the ID is 0, there will be an average of that line and the previous 3 in column Z on that row.

Comment: If it was an overall average you wanted, then you could just do the above and then take an average of that column.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A3:A53,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A3:A53=0,),0)-5):INDEX(A3:A53,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A3:A53=0,),0)-1))
```